# Full Text Indexing for SQL Compact Server

Tags: sql-server-ce, full-text-indexing

I have an Select/Update query that takes a long time, I did research on full-text-indexing and this looks like it would help

However, SQL Server Compact does not support full-text-index and the program uses a `.sdf` file

Is there anyway that I can simulate this feature using SQL Server Compact 4?

**EDIT: ADDED CODE**

The database has two columns called words and timesUsed. It uses the following as a select statement

```
SELECT TimesUsed, Word FROM Predictions 
WHERE (Word LIKE @partialWord) ORDER BY TimesUsed DESC
```

and is referred to in the code as

```
 PredTable = PredTA.GetDataByPartialWord(combo)
            If PredTable.Count > 1 Then MsgBox("problem")
            If PredTable.Count = 1 Then PredTA.Update(PredTable(0).TimesUsed + 1, combo)
            If PredTable.Count = 0 Then PredTA.Insert(combo, 1)
```

This block of code takes around .3 - .7 seconds to run

Comment: Maybe you should start by investigating why the select takes a long time. You could simply be missing indexes!

Comment: what other index could i use that does the same as full-text-index?

Comment: Show us some code, please